# ¿Como convertir data en numero JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Al imprimir una variable esta me muestra 5 resultados que he obtenido de la base de datos.

- Dirección General.
- Auxiliar Administrativo.
- Administración y Recursos Humanos.
- Finanzas y Contabilidad.
- Publicidad y Mercadotecnia.

Pero quisiera saber cómo puedo convertir estos 5 resultados en un número como tal; es decir, que la consola no me imprima como tal esos resultados sino que me los cuente.

**CODIGO**

```
for (var j = 0; j < resultado[i].usuario.areas.length; j++)
{                       
    var areas = resultado[i].usuario.areas[j];                      
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes mostrar tu código de como esta?

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu codigo actual para poder trabajar sobre el? asi no se puede saber lo que quieres.

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta...

Comment: imprime la variable j

Comment: Si no usas esos datos en otra cosa, entonces mejor te conviene hacer un `COUNT` y obtener directamente el número de resultados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu lo que haces es iterar por todos los elementos. Para sacar el número de todos los elementos, lo puedes hacer por medio de la propiedad `length`:

```
resultado[i].usuario.areas.length //sería 5
```

Si lo que quieres es que en vez de texto, saque el número que ocuparían, utiliza la variable de control:

```
for (var j = 0; j < resultado[i].usuario.areas.length; j++)
{                       
    var areas = j+1;  

}
```

Comment: Vaya que torpe, muchas gracias.